# Needing to manually run __load on lazy loaded object in manytomany scenario using Doctrine in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a setup with three entities, as you can see by the schema below, Person and Project are joined in a many-to-many relationship by Role.

The problem arises in a function I wrote that will grab the People related to a Project, and Projects related to a Person. In these cases, I get proxy objects from doctrine, as expected. However, I'm unable to access properties of these objects without running __load on them.

Here's a slice of the schema:

```
class Person{

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Role", mappedBy="project")
     */
    protected $roles;

}

class Project{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Role", mappedBy="person")
     */
    protected $roles;
}

class Role{

   /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="roles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="personId", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $person;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project", inversedBy="roles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="projectId", referencedColumnName="id")
     *
     */
    protected $production;
}
```

And here's some code that gets all the People on a single Project

```
class Project{
    public function getPeople(){

        $roles = $this->getRoles();
        $people = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();

        foreach($roles as $role){

            $person = $role->getPerson();
            $people->add($person);
        }
        return $people;
    }
}
```

Now, here's where I'm getting unexpected behavior. The following code will echo nothing:

```
class Project{    
    public function getPeoplesNames(){
        foreach($this->getPeople() as $person){
            echo $person->getName();
        }
    }
}
```

But this code will echo names, as expected

```
class Project{    
    public function getPeoplesNames(){
        foreach($this->getPeople() as $person){
            $person->__load();
            echo $person->getName();
        }
    }
}
```

Is this expected behavior based on something I'm doing? Can anyone tell what the issue is? Thanks a bunch-

Comment: It's not expected behavior.  How are you loading the project entity?  A simple find($id) or are you doing a query with joins?

Comment: And while not directly related, there is no real reason to use an ArrayCollection in getPersons();  A simple array will do the job.  You need ArrayCollections on your relations but not on other stuff.

Comment: I'm using a simple findBy() to load the project entities in the example above.

Thank you for the response...I didn't think I was doing anything wrong...I'm going to continue working with the code and I'll post if I figure out what's wrong with it-

Comment: I suppose you could try the ever popular clearing of the cache.

Comment: Well there you go. I swear I was experiencing this issue...just because I'm an alcoholic and the only photo I have of it is really blurry, that doesn't make it not true. I went back to work on it today and it was working correctly, must have been a cache:clear. Thanks for the help!